# How to Apache Calcite query mongo DB by using Relational Algebra

Tags: apache-calcite

Can any one share sample code for Apache Calcite querying MongoDB by using relational algebra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Calcite | Quering data from MongoDB by using Relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373953/apache-calcite-quering-data-from-mongodb-by-using-relational-algebra)

Comment: Above one i tried